# Is there a way to sync only one partition?

Tags: filesystems, synchronization, cache, block-device, buffer

Is there a way to sync only one partition instead of all partitions?

Something like "sync /dev/sdc1".

Comment: No. As far as I am aware. Good question, though.

Answer (score 12):

you can remount with sync option and then remount it back with async:

```
mount -o remount,sync /mountpoint
mount -o remount,async /mountpoint
```

Using remount option will not mess with processes using remounted filesystem.

Comment: Why do you think that 2 remounts are necessary? In at least 2.6.32 kernel do_remount_sb performs sync_filesystem which is the same function that is called in syncfs system call introduced in https://lwn.net/Articles/433384/.

Answer (score 5):

There is a standard function to synchronize data (and metadata) of one file: [`fsync`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fsync.html). There is no standard or common shell command to access it, but you can use perl's `sync` method in [`IO::Handle`](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Handle.html):

```
perl -MIO::File -e 'new IO::File($ARGV[0], "r+")->sync()' filename
```

There is no standard or common function or shell command to synchronize just one partition.

On [recent Linux systems](http://linux.die.net/man/2/syncfs), there is the [`syncfs`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.39/fs/sync.c#L135) system call (introduced in kernel 2.6.39, and exposed since [glibc 2.14](http://sourceware.org/ml/libc-hacker/2011-03/msg00005.html)). I don't think this system call is exposed in coreutils or util-linux yet.

Comment: The last sentence about `syncfs` is the most relevant part.

Answer (score 5):

It is now possible with `sync -f`:

```
sync -f /mount/point
```

Excerpt from sync(1):

```
       -f, --file-system
              sync the file systems that contain the files
```

Answer (score 3):

Mounting the partition with the `sync` option may be a solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the `sync` utility that flushes data in memory to disk, then the answer is no.  This is due to the fact that `sync` is generally used during a shutdown or reboot procedure, where it's advisable to get data written safely to disk, and the real target of the operation is memory, not the disks, and getting that buffered data out of RAM to somewhere safe.  The disks are just where the data ends up.

Answer (score 1):

If btrfs:

```
btrfs filesystem sync /path/under/mountpoint
```