# how can I sync a specific device?

Tags: hard-disk, disk, synchronization

Is there a way to `sync` a specific device in Linux?

This would be used to ensure that, e.g., writes to a USB thumb drive have taken place without waiting for queued writes from a video processing job to complete on an unrelated RAID array.

If there is a system call / combination of parameters that can achieve this, I could probably write a simple C wrapper. If someone knows of a Ubuntu package that can do this, that'd be even better.

Comment: Closely related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28554/is-there-a-way-to-sync-only-one-partition

Comment: Have you heard of stripes lvm? Another choice is with rsync --Only update the changes in another partition or folder like a cvs or subversion.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot [sync(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sync.2.html) a device, and that does not have any sense. You are syncing a [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) (not the device mounting it) with `syncfs` or the entire [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache) with `sync`.

The `sync(2)`  [syscall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) is called by the [sync(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sync.1.html) command.

<sup>(I don't know of any usual command doing a `syncfs`)</sup>

However, you could flush the buffers for a file system by using the Linux specific [syncfs(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sync.2.html) syscall. So write a simple C wrapper doing that.

For an opened [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor), you could use [fsync(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fsync.2.html) or `fdatasync`

Notice that unmounting a file system is generally flushing it.

Comment: Well, *sync*ing a device is obviously not what *sync(2)* does. However, I believe *sync*ing a device nevertheless has a "sense". It is observed that on Linux, "dd" happily returns as soon as the commanded write operations have been queued by the OS, and does not wait for the data to reach the target. So Linux does buffering of writes to block devices, not only to files residing on filesystems. And a way to perform a *sync* of such buffers is what I was asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Direct I/O, this will avoid the need to `sync`.  Some filesystems can be forced to use it via mount option (`dio`).

Comment: But direct I/O would greatly decrease performance....